# Meshing of Point Clouds from a 3Dlaser scanner

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, triangulation, point-clouds

Is there any  package/software which can do Meshing of Point Clouds in real time?

What is the data structure used to represent 3D Point Clouds ?

Comment: Seems like 2 separate questions here?

Answer (score 11):

**[MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)** is a great one for meshing [point clouds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud).

Look under *Filters > Re-meshing, simplification and reconstruction*. **Ball Pivoting Surface Reconstruction** and **Poisson Reconstruction** are good ones.

Here you can find a tutorial on [Meshing Point Clouds](http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.com/2009/09/meshing-point-clouds.html) using MeshLab.

As for representing your point cloud the easiest format to use is the XYZ format:

```
X1 Y1 Z1
X2 Y2 Z2
etc.
```

Another good format that is relatively easy to use is [Object (OBJ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj) model format.

Comment: I used it to reconstruct alpha shapes, but the `asc` format didn't worked for me. Thanks for mentioning the `xyz` format here, which did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

MeshLab http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/

Comment: can it do that real-time..as the data is acquired from the lidar

Comment: @iceman For typical applications you are probably going to take several scans and then manually register them off-line to make one big point cloud before you think about meshing them. A single scan is limited by occlusions in the line of sight.

Answer (score 3):

[Marc Levoy](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~levoy/publications.html#polygon-meshes)'s website contains links to packages used to create several famous 3D models, but they are not real time. In particular, [VripPack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/software/vrip/) and [ZipPack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/software/zippack/). He has some papers on doing it in real time too, I think, but they lack packaged implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Geomagic can do it very well http://www.geomagic.com, but not in real time and it is very expensive.  I think a lot of users of lidar data are moving away from meshing and are focused improving the methods of viewing point-clouds- extracting surface normals to allow lighting and scaling up the point sizes intelligently to fill holes.

Answer (score 0):

3DRACS is the best option. try it Its easy and fast. http://real3d.pk/3dracs.html